# Insert Pivot Table in protected sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-protection

I'm creating an Excel file that will have protected sheets (to disallow users from deleting pictures/logos, and selecting certain cells). However, I also want to allow the user to insert Pivot Tables.

Nearly all functionality within the "Insert" tab is greyed out once the sheet is protected.

I have check-marked all of the boxes when I locked the sheet (except "edit objects", so that the user cannot delete pictures), but it still doesn't allow the user to insert tables/pivots/etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm assuming the same issue is correlated with the inability to refresh pivot tables on protected sheets (without the use of VBA). Therefore, I'm beginning to think a resolution isn't feasible. I'll have to restructure my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A protected worksheet means you can't change, move or delete data in it. Includes inserting a PivotTable.

Review [Protect a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6) to learn the details.